# Laravel validation Form - Don't accept number into double quotes

Tags: laravel, forms, validation, rules

I have this POST request:

```
{
    "documentType": "1",
    "metadata": []
}
```

And i have this validation rules:

```
const POST_RULES = [
    'documentType' => 'required|int',
    'metadata' => 'array',
];
```

The problem is:

I don't want accept this value of documentType ("1") because it's a string. Users of the application can send a string.

I need to accept only number (1, 2, 3, 4 etc ...) whitout double quotes.

It's possible to create rule for that ?

Thank's in advance,

Comment: if it passed validation it is a valid integer, cast it to an integer if you have to

Comment: Thank's, so i need obligatory to set type for my attribute like this:  $payload['documentType'] = (int)$payload['documentType']; @lagbox

Answer (score 1):

In the POST request, send number without quotes

```
{
    "documentType": 1,
    "metadata": []
}
```

You required an INT, not a STRING.

Or, you can accept the "1" and then check if that is a number:

```
if (is_numeric($request->documentType)) {
   // Do other stuff

   return true
}
```

Comment: Thank's for you"r response, Users of the application can send a string. I can't make control here.

Comment: @Mitsukk please check my post edit, please

Comment: thank's i did that :)